# Color hue slider for color picker

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help me with this, I tried many different solutions, none of them worked, and nobody on stackflow knew why. So I deleted it, so can you try give me the code, for the hue slider in this color picker, the id of the hue slider is “Colorbar”, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- This is based on DillingerLee's great template here:
    https://github.com/Team-Code/KA_Offline -->
    <html> 
     <head>
        <title>Color Picker</title> 
        <link rel="icon" href="../Top-Logo.png">
    </head>
    <style>
    body {font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;}
    .No-Underline {text-decoration: none;}
    h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    #Topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(14, 5, 255)
    }
    #Topbar h1 {
    color: white;
    }
    #Pages {
    float: left;
    height: 870px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212)
    }
    #About {
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    height: 870px;
    width: 1700px;
    }
    #About h2 {
    text-align:center;
    }
    #About p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .Image-Div {
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    float: right;
    width: 13%;
    height: 92.3%;
    }
    .Text-Div {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 92%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 250px;
    }
    .Text-Div * {
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .Content-Button {
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    width: 221px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .Content-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    }
    .Page-Button {
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .Page-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    }
    .Select-Button {
    background-color: rgb(180, 228, 237);
    color: rgb(22, 55, 222);
    border-left: 5px solid rgb(22, 55, 222);
    }
    .Select-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(149, 203, 240);
    }
    .Reload-Button {
    width: 125px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 207);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 25px
    }
    .Reload-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(141, 141, 148);
    }
    .Warning {
    background-color: red;
    color: rgb(237, 222, 5);
    font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #Color-Picker {
    display: flex;
    width: 630px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    line-height: 100px;
    }
    #color_canvas {
        border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    }
    #color_canvas:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Colorbar {
        border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
        height: 295px;
        width: 40px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #Colorbar:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Color-Word {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #Color-Word:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Color-Background {
    width: 230px;
    height: 172px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    background-color: white;
    }
    #Color-Background:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #marker {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: 3px solid white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 450px;
        left: 600px;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    body:has(#marker:hover) #color_canvas {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="marker">
    </div>
    <div id="Topbar">
    <center>
    <h1><span>Project At All</span><h1>
    </center>
    </div>
    <h1>Information On Home Page</h1>
    <div id="Pages">
    <h2 style = "text-align: center;">Projects</h2>
    <a class="No-Underline" href="../index2.html"><button class="Page-Button">Home</button></a>
    <button class="Page-Button Select-Button">Color Picker</button>
    </div>
    <div id="About">
    <h2>Color Picker</h2>
        <div class="Image-Div">
        <h2 style = "text-align: center;">Contents</h2>
        <button class="Content-Button Select-Button">Color Picker Page</button>
        <a class="No-Underline" href="./Color_Information.html"><button class="Content-Button">What Is A Color Picker</button></a>
    <a class="No-Underline" href="./Color_Steps.html"><button class="Content-Button">Color Picker Creation Steps</button></a>
        </div>
    <div class="Text-Div">
        <div id="Color-Picker" style="text-align: left;">
        <canvas width="300px" height="300px" id="color_canvas"></canvas>
        <div style=" width:20px; margin: 0px; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 10px;">
        <canvas id="Colorbar"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div>
        <div id="Color-Word" style="line-height: 20px;">
        <p style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">RGB:<span id="RGBText"></span></p>
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">Hex:<span id="HexText"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="Color-Background"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    
     
     <script>
        var colorCanvas = document.getElementById('color_canvas');
        var colorSlider = document.getElementById('Colorbar')
        var marker = document.getElementById('marker')
        var isDown = false;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
        isDown = true;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        isDown = false;
        });
var ColorCtx = colorCanvas .getContext('2d');  // This create a 2D context for the canvas
var SliderCtx = colorSlider .getContext('2d')

// Canvas Section
var color = 'rgba(0,0,255,1)';
let gradientH = ColorCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, 0);
gradientH.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
gradientH.addColorStop(1, color);
ColorCtx .fillStyle = gradientH;
ColorCtx .fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, ColorCtx .canvas.height);


// Create a Vertical Gradient(white to black)
 let gradientV = ColorCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
 gradientV.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
 gradientV.addColorStop(1, '#000');
 ColorCtx .fillStyle = gradientV;
 ColorCtx .fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, 
 ColorCtx .canvas.height);
 
    const selectedColor = document.getElementById("Color-Background");
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }
    function pick(event, destination) {
    if (isDown == true) {
        const bounding = colorCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = event.clientX - bounding.x;
        const y = event.clientY - bounding.y;
        const pixel = ColorCtx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
        const data = pixel.data;

        const rgb = `rgb(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;

        [red, green, blue] = rgb.substring(rgb.indexOf('(') + 1, rgb.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
        // passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
        // we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
        // properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
        colorObject = {
            red,
            green,
            blue
        };
        mousePosition = {
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
        };
        destination.style.background = rgb;
        document.getElementById('RGBText').textContent = (red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue);
        document.getElementById('HexText').textContent = rgb2hex(rgb);
        marker.style.display = "block";
        marker.style.left = (mousePosition.x - 5) + 'px';
        marker.style.top = (mousePosition.y - 5) + 'px';
        return rgb;
    };
};
function pick2(event, destination,) {
const bounding = colorCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = event.clientX - bounding.x;
const y = event.clientY - bounding.y;
const pixel = ColorCtx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
const data = pixel.data;

const rgb = `rgb(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;

[red, green, blue] = rgb.substring(rgb.indexOf('(') + 1, rgb.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
// passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
// we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
// properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
colorObject = {
red,
green,
blue
};
mousePosition = {
x : event.clientX,
y : event.clientY
};
destination.style.background = rgb;
document.getElementById('RGBText').textContent = (red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue);
document.getElementById('HexText').textContent = rgb2hex(rgb);
marker.style.display = "block";
marker.style.left = (mousePosition.x - 5) + 'px';
marker.style.top = (mousePosition.y - 5) + 'px';
return rgb;
};
colorCanvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => pick2(event, selectedColor))
colorCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => pick(event, selectedColor))
//Slider Section
let gradient = SliderCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, SliderCtx . canvas.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(255, 0, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.33, "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.49, "rgb(0, 255, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.67, "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.84, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
SliderCtx .fillStyle = gradient;
SliderCtx .fillRect(0, 0, SliderCtx .canvas.width, SliderCtx .canvas.height);
     </script>
```

I tried to make the color hue slider work, but it didn't so I restarted and din't know where to start, so I am saking for a start code to help me

Comment: It looks like it works for me. https://codepen.io/Trevor-Sharp-the-sans/pen/mdoEOKp live example you may need to make the window bigger to see it... But the picker is working with your present code... Make sure you have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: I need the hue picker to work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- This is based on DillingerLee's great template here:
    https://github.com/Team-Code/KA_Offline -->
    <html> 
     <head>
        <title>Color Picker</title> 
        <link rel="icon" href="../Top-Logo.png">
    </head>
    <style>
    body {font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;}
    .No-Underline {text-decoration: none;}
    h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    #Topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(14, 5, 255)
    }
    #Topbar h1 {
    color: white;
    }
    #Pages {
    float: left;
    height: 870px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212)
    }
    #About {
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    height: 870px;
    width: 1700px;
    }
    #About h2 {
    text-align:center;
    }
    #About p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .Image-Div {
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    float: right;
    width: 13%;
    height: 92.3%;
    }
    .Text-Div {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 92%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 250px;
    }
    .Text-Div * {
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .Content-Button {
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    width: 221px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .Content-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    }
    .Page-Button {
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .Page-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    }
    .Select-Button {
    background-color: rgb(180, 228, 237);
    color: rgb(22, 55, 222);
    border-left: 5px solid rgb(22, 55, 222);
    }
    .Select-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(149, 203, 240);
    }
    .Reload-Button {
    width: 125px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 207);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 25px
    }
    .Reload-Button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(141, 141, 148);
    }
    .Warning {
    background-color: red;
    color: rgb(237, 222, 5);
    font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #Color-Picker {
    display: flex;
    width: 630px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    line-height: 100px;
    }
    #color_canvas {
        border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    }
    #color_canvas:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Colorbar {
        border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
        height: 295px;
        width: 40px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #Colorbar:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Color-Word {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #Color-Word:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Color-Background {
    width: 230px;
    height: 172px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    background-color: white;
    }
    #Color-Background:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #marker {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: 3px solid white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 450px;
        left: 600px;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #pin {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 600px;
        left: 45.32%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    body:has(#marker:hover) #color_canvas {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="marker">
    </div>
    <div id="pin">
    </div>
    <div id="Topbar">
    <center>
    <h1><span>Project At All</span><h1>
    </center>
    </div>
    <h1>Information On Home Page</h1>
    <div id="Pages">
    <h2 style = "text-align: center;">Projects</h2>
    <a class="No-Underline" href="../index2.html"><button class="Page-Button">Home</button></a>
    <button class="Page-Button Select-Button">Color Picker</button>
    </div>
    <div id="About">
    <h2>Color Picker</h2>
        <div class="Image-Div">
        <h2 style = "text-align: center;">Contents</h2>
        <button class="Content-Button Select-Button">Color Picker Page</button>
        <a class="No-Underline" href="./Color_Information.html"><button class="Content-Button">What Is A Color Picker</button></a>
    <a class="No-Underline" href="./Color_Steps.html"><button class="Content-Button">Color Picker Creation Steps</button></a>
        </div>
    <div class="Text-Div">
        <div id="Color-Picker" style="text-align: left;">
        <canvas width="300px" height="300px" id="color_canvas"></canvas>
        <div style=" width:20px; margin: 0px; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 10px;">
        <canvas id="Colorbar"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div>
        <div id="Color-Word" style="line-height: 20px;">
        <p style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">RGB:<span id="RGBText"></span></p>
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">Hex:<span id="HexText"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="Color-Background"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    
     
     <script>
        var colorCanvas = document.getElementById('color_canvas');
        var colorSlider = document.getElementById('Colorbar')
        var marker = document.getElementById('marker')
        var pin = document.getElementById('pin')
        var isDown = false;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
        isDown = true;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        isDown = false;
        });
var ColorCtx = colorCanvas .getContext('2d');  // This create a 2D context for the canvas
var SliderCtx = colorSlider .getContext('2d')

// Canvas Section
var color = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
let gradientH = ColorCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, 0);
gradientH.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
gradientH.addColorStop(1, color);
ColorCtx .fillStyle = gradientH;
ColorCtx .fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, ColorCtx .canvas.height);


// Create a Vertical Gradient(white to black)
 let gradientV = ColorCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
 gradientV.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
 gradientV.addColorStop(1, '#000');
 ColorCtx .fillStyle = gradientV;
 ColorCtx .fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, 
 ColorCtx .canvas.height);
 
    const selectedColor = document.getElementById("Color-Background");
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }
    function HSVtoRGB (hue, saturation, value) {
    let r, g, b
    const i = Math.floor(hue * 6)
    const f = hue * 6 - i
    const p = value * (1 - saturation)
    const q = value * (1 - f * saturation)
    const t = value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation)
    switch (i % 6) {
    case 0:
    r = value
    g = t
    b = p
    break
    case 1:
    r = q
    g = value
    b = p
    break
    case 2:
    r = p
    g = value
    b = t
    break
    case 3:
    r = p
    g = q
    b = value
    break
    case 4:
    r = t
    g = p
    b = value
    break
    case 5:
    r = value
    g = p
    b = q
    break
    }
    return {
    r: Math.round(r * 255),
    g: Math.round(g * 255),
    b: Math.round(b * 255)
    }
    }
    function pick(event, destination) {
    if (isDown == true) {
        const bounding = colorCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = event.clientX - bounding.x;
        const y = event.clientY - bounding.y;
        const pixel = ColorCtx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
        const data = pixel.data;

        const rgb = `rgb(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;

        [red, green, blue] = rgb.substring(rgb.indexOf('(') + 1, rgb.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
        // passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
        // we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
        // properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
        colorObject = {
            red,
            green,
            blue
        };
        mousePosition = {
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
        };
        destination.style.background = rgb;
        document.getElementById('RGBText').textContent = (red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue);
        document.getElementById('HexText').textContent = rgb2hex(rgb);
        marker.style.display = "block";
        marker.style.left = (mousePosition.x - 5) + 'px';
        marker.style.top = (mousePosition.y - 5) + 'px';
        return rgb;
    };
};
function pick2(event, destination,) {
const bounding = colorCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = event.clientX - bounding.x;
const y = event.clientY - bounding.y;
const pixel = ColorCtx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
const data = pixel.data;

const rgb = `rgb(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;

[red, green, blue] = rgb.substring(rgb.indexOf('(') + 1, rgb.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
// passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
// we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
// properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
colorObject = {
red,
green,
blue
};
mousePosition = {
x : event.clientX,
y : event.clientY
};
destination.style.background = rgb;
document.getElementById('RGBText').textContent = (red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue);
document.getElementById('HexText').textContent = rgb2hex(rgb);
marker.style.display = "block";
marker.style.left = (mousePosition.x - 6) + 'px';
marker.style.top = (mousePosition.y - 3) + 'px';
return rgb;
};
colorCanvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => pick2(event, selectedColor))
colorCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => pick(event, selectedColor))
//Slider Section
let gradient = SliderCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, SliderCtx . canvas.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(255, 0, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.33, "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.49, "rgb(0, 255, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.67, "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.84, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
SliderCtx .fillStyle = gradient;
SliderCtx .fillRect(0, 0, SliderCtx .canvas.width, SliderCtx .canvas.height);

colorSlider.addEventListener('click', event => {
const bounding = colorSlider.getBoundingClientRect();
const y = event.clientY - colorSlider.offsetTop;
const height = colorSlider.clientHeight;
const hue = parseFloat(y/ height );

mousePosition = {
x : event.clientX,
y : event.clientY
};

// update the pin
pin.style.top = mousePosition.y + 'px';

// update the palette
const color = HSVtoRGB(hue, 1, 1);
var color1 = `rgb(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b})`;
let gradientH = ColorCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, 0);
gradientH.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
gradientH.addColorStop(1, color1);
ColorCtx .fillStyle = gradientH;
ColorCtx .fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width, ColorCtx .canvas.height);


// Create a Vertical Gradient(white to black)
let gradientV = ColorCtx .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
gradientV.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
gradientV.addColorStop(1, '#000');
ColorCtx .fillStyle = gradientV;
ColorCtx .fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx .canvas.width,
ColorCtx .canvas.height);
// set the hue
colorSlider.dataset.value = hue
})
     </script>
```

Comment: What would this code dump mean, as an "answer"?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your script includes two functions for retrieving the colour from the first canvas (`#color_canvas`).

- `pick()`
- `pick2()`

Your script creates event listeners which invoke these functions:

- `colorCanvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => pick2(event, selectedColor))`
- `colorCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => pick(event, selectedColor))`

But your script has no functions for retrieving colour from the second canvas (`#Colorbar`) and no event listeners. That’s why your hue slider doesn’t do anything.

Comment: I made a start, and I am now wondering why my hueSlider is getting the wrong value, here is the code, Id = "Colorbar" for hueslider

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it is simple, use mathematics to find the hue value correctly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This is based on DillingerLee's great template here:
    https://github.com/Team-Code/KA_Offline -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Color Picker</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../Top-Logo.png" />
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    }
    .No-Underline {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #Topbar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 75px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      background: rgb(14, 5, 255);
    }
    #Topbar h1 {
      color: white;
    }
    #Pages {
      float: left;
      height: 870px;
      width: 200px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      border-right: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    }
    #About {
      border-right: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      height: 870px;
      width: 1700px;
    }
    #About h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #About p {
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .Image-Div {
      border-left: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      float: right;
      width: 13%;
      height: 92.3%;
    }
    .Text-Div {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      background-color: white;
      border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      float: right;
      width: 75%;
      height: 92%;
      overflow: auto;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 250px;
    }
    .Text-Div * {
      margin-left: 13px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .Content-Button {
      background-color: white;
      border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-bottom: 0px;
      border-left: 0px;
      border-right: 0px;
      width: 221px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .Content-Button:hover {
      background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    }
    .Page-Button {
      background-color: white;
      border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      border-bottom: 0px;
      border-left: 0px;
      border-right: 0px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .Page-Button:hover {
      background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    }
    .Select-Button {
      background-color: rgb(180, 228, 237);
      color: rgb(22, 55, 222);
      border-left: 5px solid rgb(22, 55, 222);
    }
    .Select-Button:hover {
      background-color: rgb(149, 203, 240);
    }
    .Reload-Button {
      width: 125px;
      height: 45px;
      background-color: rgb(196, 196, 207);
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 0px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 35px;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      line-height: 25px;
    }
    .Reload-Button:hover {
      background-color: rgb(141, 141, 148);
    }
    .Warning {
      background-color: red;
      color: rgb(237, 222, 5);
      font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #Color-Picker {
      display: flex;
      width: 630px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 200px;
      line-height: 100px;
    }
    #color_canvas {
      border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
    }
    #color_canvas:hover {
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Colorbar {
      border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      height: 295px;
      width: 40px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    #Colorbar:hover {
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Color-Word {
      width: 230px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      background-color: white;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #Color-Word:hover {
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #Color-Background {
      width: 230px;
      height: 172px;
      border: 2px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
      background-color: white;
    }
    #Color-Background:hover {
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #marker {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border: 3px solid white;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 450px;
      left: 600px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #pin {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 10%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 374px;
      left: 45.32%;
      width: 50px;
      height: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    body:has(#marker:hover) #color_canvas {
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    body:has(#pin:hover) #Colorbar {
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="marker"></div>
    <div id="pin"></div>
    <div id="Topbar">
      <center>
        <h1><span>Project At All</span></h1>
      </center>
    </div>
    <h1>Information On Home Page</h1>
    <div id="Pages">
      <h2 style="text-align: center">Projects</h2>
      <a class="No-Underline" href="../index2.html"
        ><button class="Page-Button">Home</button></a
      >
      <button class="Page-Button Select-Button">Color Picker</button>
    </div>
    <div id="About">
      <h2>Color Picker</h2>
      <div class="Image-Div">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Contents</h2>
        <button class="Content-Button Select-Button">Color Picker Page</button>
        <a class="No-Underline" href="./Color_Information.html"
          ><button class="Content-Button">What Is A Color Picker</button></a
        >
        <a class="No-Underline" href="./Color_Steps.html"
          ><button class="Content-Button">
            Color Picker Creation Steps
          </button></a
        >
      </div>
      <div class="Text-Div">
        <div id="Color-Picker" style="text-align: left">
          <canvas width="300px" height="300px" id="color_canvas"></canvas>
          <div
            style="
              width: 20px;
              margin: 0px;
              margin-right: 20px;
              margin-left: 10px;
            "
          >
            <canvas id="Colorbar"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div id="Color-Word" style="line-height: 20px">
              <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em">
                RGB:<span id="RGBText"></span>
              </p>
              <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em">
                Hex:<span id="HexText"></span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="Color-Background"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
        var colorCanvas = document.getElementById("color_canvas");
        var colorSlider = document.getElementById("Colorbar");
        var marker = document.getElementById("marker");
        var pin = document.getElementById("pin");
        var isDown = false;
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
          isDown = true;
        });

        document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
          isDown = false;
        });
        var ColorCtx = colorCanvas.getContext("2d"); // This create a 2D context for the canvas
        var SliderCtx = colorSlider.getContext("2d");

        // Canvas Section
        var color = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
        let gradientH = ColorCtx.createLinearGradient(
          0,
          0,
          ColorCtx.canvas.width,
          0
        );
        gradientH.addColorStop(0, "#fff");
        gradientH.addColorStop(1, color);
        ColorCtx.fillStyle = gradientH;
        ColorCtx.fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx.canvas.width, ColorCtx.canvas.height);

        // Create a Vertical Gradient(white to black)
        let gradientV = ColorCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
        gradientV.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
        gradientV.addColorStop(1, "#000");
        ColorCtx.fillStyle = gradientV;
        ColorCtx.fillRect(0, 0, ColorCtx.canvas.width, ColorCtx.canvas.height);

        const selectedColor = document.getElementById("Color-Background");
        function rgb2hex(rgb) {
          rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
          function hex(x) {
            return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
          }
          return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
        }

        function pick(event, destination) {
          if (isDown == true) {
            const bounding = colorCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = event.clientX - bounding.x;
            const y = event.clientY - bounding.y;
            const pixel = ColorCtx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
            const data = pixel.data;

            const rgb = `rgb(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;

            ([red, green, blue] = rgb
              .substring(rgb.indexOf("(") + 1, rgb.lastIndexOf(")"))
              .split(/,\s*/)),
              // passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
              // we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
              // properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
              (colorObject = {
                red,
                green,
                blue,
              });
            mousePosition = {
              x: event.clientX,
              y: event.clientY,
            };
            destination.style.background = rgb;
            document.getElementById("Topbar").style.background = rgb;
            document.getElementById("RGBText").textContent =
              red + ", " + green + ", " + blue;
            document.getElementById("HexText").textContent = rgb2hex(rgb);
            marker.style.display = "block";
            marker.style.left = mousePosition.x - 5 + "px";
            marker.style.top = mousePosition.y - 5 + "px";
            return rgb;
          }
        }
        function pick2(event, destination) {
          const bounding = colorCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          const x = event.clientX - bounding.x;
          const y = event.clientY - bounding.y;
          const pixel = ColorCtx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
          const data = pixel.data;

          const rgb = `rgb(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;

          ([red, green, blue] = rgb
            .substring(rgb.indexOf("(") + 1, rgb.lastIndexOf(")"))
            .split(/,\s*/)),
            // passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
            // we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
            // properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
            (colorObject = {
              red,
              green,
              blue,
            });
          mousePosition = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
          };
          destination.style.background = rgb;
          document.getElementById("Topbar").style.background = rgb;
          document.getElementById("RGBText").textContent =
            red + ", " + green + ", " + blue;
          document.getElementById("HexText").textContent = rgb2hex(rgb);
          marker.style.display = "block";
          marker.style.left = mousePosition.x + "px";
          marker.style.top = mousePosition.y + "px";
          return rgb;
        }
        colorCanvas.addEventListener("click", (event) =>
          pick2(event, selectedColor)
        );
        colorCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>
          pick(event, selectedColor)
        );
        //Slider Section
        let gradient = SliderCtx.createLinearGradient(
          0,
          0,
          0,
          SliderCtx.canvas.height
        );
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.33, "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.49, "rgb(0, 255, 255)");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.67, "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.84, "rgb(255, 0, 255)");
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
        SliderCtx.fillStyle = gradient;
        SliderCtx.fillRect(
          0,
          0,
          SliderCtx.canvas.width,
          SliderCtx.canvas.height
        );

        colorSlider.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          const bounding = colorSlider.getBoundingClientRect();
          const y = event.clientY - colorSlider.offsetTop;
          const height = colorSlider.clientHeight;
          const hue = parseFloat(y / height);

          mousePosition = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
          };

          // update the pin
          pin.style.top = mousePosition.y + "px";

          // update the palette
          const color1 = HSVtoRGB(hue, 1, 1);
          color = `rgb(${color1.r}, ${color1.g}, ${color1.b})`;
          let gradientH = ColorCtx.createLinearGradient(
            0,
            0,
            ColorCtx.canvas.width,
            0
          );
          gradientH.addColorStop(0, "#ffffff");
          gradientH.addColorStop(1, color);
          ColorCtx.fillStyle = gradientH;
          ColorCtx.fillRect(
            0,
            0,
            ColorCtx.canvas.width,
            ColorCtx.canvas.height
          );

          // Create a Vertical Gradient(white to black)
          let gradientV = ColorCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
          gradientV.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
          gradientV.addColorStop(1, "#000000");
          ColorCtx.fillStyle = gradientV;
          ColorCtx.fillRect(
            0,
            0,
            ColorCtx.canvas.width,
            ColorCtx.canvas.height
          );
          // set the hue
          colorSlider.dataset.value = hue;
        });
        colorSlider.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
          if (isDown) {
            const bounding = colorSlider.getBoundingClientRect();
            const y = event.clientY - colorSlider.offsetTop;
            const height = colorSlider.clientHeight;
            const hue = parseFloat(y / height);

            mousePosition = {
              x: event.clientX,
              y: event.clientY,
            };

            // update the pin
            pin.style.top = mousePosition.y + "px";

            // update the palette
            const color1 = HSVtoRGB(hue, 1, 1);
            color = `rgb(${color1.r}, ${color1.g}, ${color1.b})`;
            let gradientH = ColorCtx.createLinearGradient(
              0,
              0,
              ColorCtx.canvas.width,
              0
            );
            gradientH.addColorStop(0, "#ffffff");
            gradientH.addColorStop(1, color);
            ColorCtx.fillStyle = gradientH;
            ColorCtx.fillRect(
              0,
              0,
              ColorCtx.canvas.width,
              ColorCtx.canvas.height
            );

            // Create a Vertical Gradient(white to black)
            let gradientV = ColorCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
            gradientV.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
            gradientV.addColorStop(1, "#000000");
            ColorCtx.fillStyle = gradientV;
            ColorCtx.fillRect(
              0,
              0,
              ColorCtx.canvas.width,
              ColorCtx.canvas.height
            );
            // set the hue
            colorSlider.dataset.value = hue;
          }
        });
        function HSVtoRGB(hue, saturation, value) {
          let r, g, b;
          const i = Math.floor(hue * 6);
          const f = hue * 6 - i;
          const p = value * (1 - saturation);
          const q = value * (1 - f * saturation);
          const t = value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation);
          switch (i % 6) {
            case 0:
              r = value;
              g = t;
              b = p;
              break;
            case 1:
              r = q;
              g = value;
              b = p;
              break;
            case 2:
              r = p;
              g = value;
              b = t;
              break;
            case 3:
              r = p;
              g = q;
              b = value;
              break;
            case 4:
              r = t;
              g = p;
              b = value;
              break;
            case 5:
              r = value;
              g = p;
              b = q;
          }
          return {
            r: Math.round(r * 255),
            g: Math.round(g * 255),
            b: Math.round(b * 255),
          };
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This surprisingly works well, so here it is for anyone if they want.(it only works for a certain screen size, I will report when I make it responsive)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).